# Check if last element was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to find out if the last `td` of an `tr` was clicked. This is my HTML example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Clicked</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And this is my currently javascript code (not working like that):

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
    if ($(this).find('td').is(':last-child')){
        alert("Last td clicked!");
    }
});
```

**Note**: I need to use the `tr-selector` for other purpose. So it it important, that the on click refers to the `tr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that **the event hander is common to all the `<td>` elements and want to distinguish between the last element**

**Without changing the event handler:**

The event object holds the reference of the element that was clicked. This can be used.

The [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property in the `event` object contains the reference of the element that is actually clicked. jQuery [`is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is/) can be used to check if the element is the last in the `<tr>`.

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
    console.log($(e.target).is($(this).find('td:last')));
    // OR
    // console.log($(e.target).is(':last-child'));
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vsf49g8q/)

**Binding event on `<td>`**

The event can be bind on the `<td>` elements inside the `<table>` and [`:last-child`](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) selector can be used with [`is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is/) to check if the element that is clicked is the last child.

```
$('table tr').on('click', 'td', function(e) {
    console.log($(this).is(':last-child'));
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vsf49g8q/3/)

Comment: I was trying something like this. Good one. +1

Comment: Second version is not checking last child , is checking last `td` in whole table. Add more rows to verify

Comment: @charlietfl Right. Used `:last-child` selector as suggested by devJunk in the other answer

Comment: @Sylnois Welcome. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

Try like following using `tr td:last-child` selector.

```js
$('table').on('click', 'tr td:last-child', function (e) {
    alert("Last td clicked!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Clicked</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATE:** as per updated question

```js
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    if($(e.target).is(':last-child')) {
        alert("Last td clicked!");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Clicked</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need that `.find()`. Also, do you want to check if the last `td`or las `tr` was clicked? Either way, you just have to do it like this:

```
$('table').on('click', 'td', function(e) {
    if($(this).is(':last-child')){
        alert("Last td clicked!");
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zzk3j9n5/)**

Answer (score 1):

Add the event listener directly to the last child

Html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Clicked</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr td:last-child', function(e) {
    alert("Last td clicked!");    
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81nko6o3/)